# grouping, percentage, and barchart in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, bar-chart

I am very new to Python, and I am trying to plot a bar chart that shows the `winner_rank_status` percentage, and within each bar, I want to show the percentage of the winner (colour).

My dataset is like:

[image]

The code that I wrote:

```
Q3_df=games_df[['winner','winner_rank_status']]
Q3_df=Q3_df.groupby(['winner_rank_status','winner']).size().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: round(100*x/x.sum(),2))
Q3_df=Q3_df.unstack()
ax= Q3_df.plot(
    kind='bar',
    stacked=True,
    figsize=(14,7),
    rot=0,
    title='Effect of piece colour and winner rating status on the result',
    color=['black','grey','white'],
    edgecolor='black',
    
)
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center',color='b')
```

And it's the result that I get:

[image]

This result is wrong as it shows 100% for all categories!!! I need to show each category (Equal, Higher, Lower) their true percentage and then within each category the proportion of each colour...

Would you please guide me on how I can achieve it?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a different color to the labels for each set of bars. To get the percentage where all 9 values sum to 100, you could divide by the total number games:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

winner_options = ['black', 'draw', 'white']
rank_options = ['lower', 'equal', 'higher']
Q3_df = pd.DataFrame({'winner_rank_status': pd.Categorical(np.random.choice(rank_options, 1000, p=[.46, .07, .47]), rank_options),
                      'winner': pd.Categorical(np.random.choice(winner_options, 1000, p=[.51, .03, .46]), winner_options)})
Q3_rank_winner_df = Q3_df.groupby(['winner_rank_status', 'winner']).size().groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda x: np.round(100 * x / len(Q3_df), 2))
Q3_rank_winner_df = Q3_rank_winner_df.unstack()
ax = Q3_rank_winner_df.plot(
    kind='bar',
    stacked=True,
    figsize=(14, 7),
    rot=0,
    title='Effect of piece colour and winner rating status on the result',
    color=['black', 'grey', 'white'],
    edgecolor='black')
for bars, color in zip(ax.containers, ['skyblue', 'navy', 'darkblue']):
    ax.bar_label(bars, label_type='center', color=color)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.02], loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with labels in different colors]

The new requirements are a bit confusing. One might add the percentages of each rank at the top of the bars:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

winner_options = ['black', 'draw', 'white']
rank_options = ['lower', 'equal', 'higher']
Q3_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'winner_rank_status': pd.Categorical(np.random.choice(rank_options, 1000, p=[.65, .05, .30]), rank_options),
     'winner': pd.Categorical(np.random.choice(winner_options, 1000, p=[.46, .07, .47]), winner_options)})
Q3_rank_winner_df = Q3_df.groupby(['winner_rank_status', 'winner']).size().groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda x: np.round(100 * x / x.sum(), 2))
Q3_rank_winner_df = Q3_rank_winner_df.unstack()
ax = Q3_rank_winner_df.plot(
    kind='bar',
    stacked=True,
    figsize=(14, 7),
    rot=0,
    title='Effect of piece colour and winner rating status on the result',
    color=['black', 'grey', 'white'],
    edgecolor='black')
for bars, color in zip(ax.containers, ['skyblue', 'navy', 'darkblue']):
    ax.bar_label(bars, label_type='center', color=color)

Q3_rank_df = Q3_df.groupby(['winner_rank_status']).size() * 100 / len(Q3_df)
for row, percent in enumerate(Q3_rank_df):
    ax.text(row, 103, f'{percent:.02f} %', color='navy', ha='center', va='center')
ax.margins(y=0.08)  # more space on top

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.02], loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: adding the rank percentages on top of the bars]

Comment: Sorry JohnC, I just noticed that it is still not the answer. If you look at the numbers inside, each bar is not adding to be 100%.
The outer higher category is correct; the sum is 100%, but not each bar.
Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: In the original answer (see [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68861834/revisions)), the 3 bars for e.g. 'lower' summed to 100. Do you want that again? Or something else?

Comment: Each of these answers is partly true, the correct answer is: 
-The summation of all main categories will be 100. It means Lower+Equal+Higher=100. -Now each bar has its own percentage on black, white, and draw. but still, the summation inside each bar should 100. For example: in the lower bar" black+white+draw=100 With your first answer, the second part was correct, and your second answer covers only the first part. I need to cover both parts! Thanks